# how to do create a field in SAS that consider more fields at the same time

Tags: sas, dataset

I have a table in `SAS` with `n` fields called `check1, check2, ... , checkN`. Every of this fields can be "OK" or "KO". I want to generate a field that is "OK" if every of the check is "OK" and it is "KO" if even one of the checks is "KO". How can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the WHICHC() function, along with Boolean check to see if it's greater than zero. You don't need to declare an array if you have a naming convention.

```
 Flag = whichc('KO', of check1-checkN) >0;
```

EDIT:

```
If WHICHC('KO', of check1-checkN)>0 then flag = 'KO';
Else flag='OK';
```

Comment: If all fields contain either OK or KO then you could use the `min` or `max` functions instead

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to declare the array, and do a simple 'do' loop across the fields.
In this code, I've added in a step that tells the program to stop scanning checkn if one of the fields has "KO". 
I've set up some sample data where n=4.

```
data dataset;
input ID $ check1 $ check2 $ check3 $ check4 $;
cards;
A OK OK OK OK
B OK OK OK KO
C KO OK OK OK
D KO KO KO OK
;
run;

data dataset;
set dataset;
array check_array{4} check1-check4;
do i=1 to 4;
if result ne "KO" then do;
if check_array{i}="OK" then result="OK"; else result="KO";
end;
end;
run;
```